# Не работает простая анимация react-spring

Tags: reactjs

Хотел анимировать появление заголовка и попробовать библиотеку react-spring. Подключил ее
npm i -D react-spring

создаю простую анимацию появления заголовка но она не работает, при этом никаких ошибок нет ни в браузере не в терминале

вот код

```
import React from 'react';
import './MainPage.css';
import {Spring} from 'react-spring';

const MainPage = ()=> {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="header">Сканер рекламной продукции</h1>
             <Spring from={{opacity:0}} to={{opacity:1}} config={{duration:2000}}>
                {
                    (props) => (<h2 style ={props} className="subHeader">Кнопка нажата</h2>)
                }
            </Spring>
         </div>
    )
}
export default MainPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался это устаревший туториал был. Через useSpring и animation.div все работает